# python customize existing built-in exception

Tags: python, exception

For example in this code, I want my script behavior this way.

when run to b=a[2], or any line will raise an exception, and no matter what is the exception. I want the script stop, and raise a customized red error message like: 'LOL!!!'

How to implement that?

```
try:
    a = [1,2]
    b = a[2]
except:
    raise something
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try:
    a = [1,2]
    b = a[2]
except IndexError:
    raise Exception('LOL!')
```

This works because the stament a[2] throws an IndexError. There are only 2 elements in a, and a[2] fetches the third (counting from zero).

... Alright...

```
class YourCustomException(Exception):
    pass

try:
    a = [1,2]
    raise YourCustomException('LOL')
except YourCustomException:
    print('NOW WHAT?')
```

Comment: thank you. But it's not the answer I need. I mean, the Exception are not able to predict. I need a method to raise my custom exception message, and no matter what it is the original exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about raising exception at https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise

Exception hirearchy is https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy

Here is your required answer,

```
try:
    a = [1,2]
    b = a[2]
#except Exception:
except IndexError: 
    raise Exception("Lol")
```